# Update buffer from file after Neomake runs

Tags: neovim, neomake

I have a few Neomake definitions which work well for me, but one thing I can't quite get my head around is automatic lint fixes with `standard --fix`. Here's what I have:

```
let g:neomake_javascript_standardfix_maker = {
    \ 'exe': 'standard',
    \ 'args': '--fix',
    \ 'errorformat': '%-G%.%#'
    \ }
let g:neomake_javascript_enabled_makers = ['standardfix', 'jest', 'standard']
call neomake#configure#automake('w')
set autoread
au FocusGained *.js :checktime
```

Unfortunately, the buffer doesn't update after `standard --fix` runs (although I've confirmed it does write the correct file with fixed syntax).

I suppose my ideal behaviour would be: linter fixes what it can fix, and location list pops open as it does now but with only those issues that `--fix` doesn't take care of automatically, like unused variables.

Comment: I feel like ALE is probably a reasonable solution, but I was hoping to continue using neomake for most things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post an answer with my workaround solution (using ALE) in case it helps anyone else, but will accept any other answer that more directly addresses the question.

My main issue is that I don't use Neomake solely for linting: to take the example of JavaScript, it's being used as a test runner on save and I could see launching staging build tasks from it too (React Native test builds, for example). I think I have ALE and Neomake cooperating, at least to be going on with:

```
" Suppress ALE warning about conflicts with Neomake
let g:ale_emit_conflict_warnings = 0

" JavaScript make/test
highlight NeomakeErrorMsg ctermfg=1 ctermbg=18
highlight NeomakeWarningMsg ctermfg=16 ctermbg=18
let g:neomake_error_sign = {
    \ 'text': '●',
    \ 'texthl': 'NeomakeErrorMsg'
    \ }
let g:neomake_warning_sign = {
    \ 'text': '●',
    \ 'texthl': 'NeomakeWarningMsg'
    \ }
let g:neomake_open_list = 2

" This reads config from a file specifying a custom Jest
" reporter (see below) making it easier to parse output with
" a Vim errorformat 
let g:neomake_javascript_jest_maker = {
    \ 'exe': './node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js',
    \ 'args': [ '-c=./vim-jest.json', '--no-watchman' ],
    \ 'errorformat':
        \ '%f:%l:%c:%t:%m,' .
        \ '%-G%.%#'
    \ }

" By setting this explicitly, we overwrite the default
" (so Neomake shouldn't attempt to launch standard/eslint)
let g:neomake_javascript_enabled_makers = ['jest']

call neomake#configure#automake('w')

" linting
let g:ale_sign_error = '▶▶'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '▶▶'
highlight ALEErrorSign ctermfg=1 ctermbg=18
highlight ALEWarningSign ctermfg=16 ctermbg=18
let g:ale_linters = {
    \ 'javascript': ['standard']
    \ }
let g:ale_fixers = {
    \ 'javascript': ['standard']
    \ }
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
```

My `vim-jest.json` contains any Jest config I need per project, at minimum this:

```
{
  "reporters": [ "jest-simple-reporter" ]
}
```

[jest-simple-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-simple-reporter) is a very rough reporter I cooked up to distill Jest's rather rangy output down to one line per fixture. It does need to be installed in the current project's `devDependencies` though, because of the separate config for Vim, it doesn't need to be used in the `test` script or project Jest config.

Interestingly, when I turn off `ale_fix_on_save`, Neomake's warning/error signs seem to take precedence in the gutter. Only after I have the test passing do the linter's signs appear. Works pretty nicely, errors are fixed on save and those that can't be fixed are indicated, co-existing nicely with test failure signage.

Comment: If you're using ALE you don't need neomake

Comment: I mentioned in the answer above that I wasn't using neomake for linting.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm a bit confused though. *"I don't use Neomake solely for linting"* - implies that you are using it for linting + other things too. I found that neomake was faster for linting (at least when I tried with [eslint_d](https://github.com/mantoni/eslint_d.js)) but it still doesn't have a decent solution for applying linting fixies. For now I've just switched to ALE + eslint_d.

Comment: I meant, I was also using it as a test runner so I couldn't just remove it entirely to avoid conflicting with ALE :)